# Three times nested for each loop in XSLT for table

Tags: xml, xslt

I try to get a table from a nested XML Object. There are some complexes. Each complex has one ore more firecompartments and each firecompartment has one or more buildings. The table output should print out the name of each complex only at first row where it occures. Same for firecompartment. If possible the table rowspan should span same complexes and firecompartments too.

Here is the XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ROOT>
  <TREE>
    ...
   <RiskArea>
   <Complex>
     <k_000 value="CO1" />
     <FireCompartment>
       <ba_000 value="FC1" />
       <Building><g_000 value="B1" /></Building>
       <Building><g_000 value="B2" /></Building>
    </FireCompartment>
    <FireCompartment>
      <ba_000 value="FC2" />
      <Building><g_000 value="B3" /></Building>
    </FireCompartment>
    ....
  </Complex>
  <Complex>
    ....
  </Complex>
  </RiskArea>
 </TREE>
</ROOT>
```

Here is my xslt structure:

```
...
<fo:table-body>
 <xsl:for-each select = "/ROOT/TREE/Group/Firm/RiskArea/Complex" >
   <xsl:variable name="complex" select="./k_000/@value"/>
   <xsl:for-each select = "./FireCompartment" >
     <xsl:for-each select = "./Building" >
         ???
         HERE INSERT CODE TO FILL UP $complex with the Name of complex for 
         the first row and with empty space for other rows for same complex 
          <xsl:call-template name="rowNormal">
            <xsl:with-param name="font-size"  select="'9pt'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="colTexte" select="concat($complex,$COL,...)"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:for-each>
</fo:table-body>
```

The output should be looks like this:

```
Complex  FireC.  Building

CO1        FC1      B1
                    B2
           FC2      B3
CO2        FC3      B4
                    B5
                    B6
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could is add some checks on the position of each child node in the heirarchy to determine whether to shows the value or not.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:table-body>
         <xsl:for-each select="/ROOT/TREE/RiskArea/Complex" >
           <xsl:variable name="complex" select="k_000/@value"/>
           <xsl:for-each select="FireCompartment" >
             <xsl:variable name="firecompartment" select="ba_000/@value" />
             <xsl:variable name="firePos" select="position()" />
             <xsl:for-each select="Building" >
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>
                        <xsl:if test="$firePos = 1 and position() = 1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$complex" />
                        </xsl:if>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>
                        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$firecompartment" />
                        </xsl:if>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="g_000/@value" /></fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
             </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
         </xsl:for-each>
        </fo:table-body>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```